# How to update a data table using a button in a data grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, wpfdatagrid, crud

I am now working on a little project on school in WPF using SQLite. I have an SQLite table that has these fields: `id` (primary key), `name`, `sex`, `station`, `job`, and `date`. I have a `DataGrid` that has the `sex`, `station`, and `job` as `ComboBox`es. When I save the data from my table in an `ObservableCollection`, then the data loading in the `DataGrid` works great. My problem is now when I want to modify the values from the `DataGrid` in the SQLite table. Any idea would be nice.

Here's what I tried so far.

```
 public SQLiteConnection m_db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        SQLiteDataAdapter adap;
        DataSet ds;
        DataTable dt;
        SQLiteCommandBuilder cmdbl;
        string Query;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = Userss.GetValues();
            ds = new DataSet();
            dataGrid.BeginInit();
            ds.Tables.Add(CreateTable());
            dataGrid.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGrid.EndInit();
        }
public DataTable CreateTable()
        {
            m_db.Open();
            Query = "Select * from user";
            adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, m_db);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);
            m_db.Close();
            return dt;
        }

 private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to make those changes?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                dt = dataGrid.DataContext as DataTable;
                cmdbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adap);
                adap.Update(dt);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
            this.dataGrid.CancelEdit();
    }
```

When I press the `Update` button, the DB table remains the same.
The `ObservableCollection` works well.

Function getValues() from userss class

```
public static ObservableCollection<Userss> GetValues()
        {

            m_dd.Open();
            string sql = "select * from user";
            userCol.Clear();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dd);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string sex1 = reader["sex"].ToString();
                string station1 = reader["station"].ToString();
                string job1 = reader["job"].ToString();
                string data1 = reader["date"].ToString();
                userCol.Add(new Userss()
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                    Name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                    Sex = (Sex)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sex), sex1),
                    Station = (Stations)Enum.Parse(typeof(Stations), station1),
                    Job = (Jobs)Enum.Parse(typeof(Jobs), job1),
                    Date = Convert.ToDateTime(data1)
                });
            }
            m_dd.Close();
            return userCol;

        }
```

Comment: I'm assuming the data table updates correctly but the database doesn't change at all?

Comment: Nothing is happening on the db...

Comment: You're not executing any SQL when you update the data table.

Comment: What is `Userss.GetValues()`?

Comment: I edited, I used the INotifyPropertyChanged in the Userss class, should I post the hole class? And thanks for the edit dyamanoid